# Node setup for transparent wire fence PBR texture

Tags: texturing, node-editor, transparency, pbr

So i downloaded a PBR texture for [wire fence](https://cc0textures.com/view.php?tex=Fence06) but i don't know how to properly setup the node to make it transparent like in this preview

[image]

Usually for PBR i only use diffuse, roughness, and normal, sometimes displacement, but with this wire fence texture there is "mask" and "met" image and i don't know where to put them

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use the mask on the alpha socket, to determine transparency

I suspect the one called met is for metallic.

[image]

Comment: thanks it worked!

Comment: If the answer works for you mark it as accepted. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer